# Update textbox through vlookup if value not in range

Tags: if-statement, vlookup

I'm using this code

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets("cash").Range("BF:BH")
    Price.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox2.Value, myRange, 2, 0)
End Sub
```

Select value from textbox2 using vlookup to match value selected from textbox2 in price.  If the value is not included in textbox2  there is last price shown.
I need if I entered value not in range no price shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the value before trying to do the Vlookup.

Also when using `On Error Resume Next` turn the error handling back on as soon as possible.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets("cash").Range("BF:BH")

    Price.Value = ""
    On Error Resume Next
        Price.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox2.Value, myRange, 2, 0)
    On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```